# pyQt5 matplotlib on key press image slices

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, keyevent

Matplotlib does not respond to key presses while embedded in PyQt5. I have verified that key presses work with Tkinter. This is my first PyQt5 experience. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have tried to set the focus on canvas by doing. All this is to display 3D volumetric data, which you can think of as a stack of images. Together, they describe a 3D structure. For example, magnetic resonance imaging (MRI)

```
self.canvas.setFocusPolicy( QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus )
self.canvas.setFocus()
```

however that returns an error:

```
self.canvas.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
AttributeError: 'InputCanvas' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

This is the code I have:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from skimage import io
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QSizePolicy
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as 
FigureCanvas


class App(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.left = 10
    self.top = 10
    self.title = 'PYQT'
    self.width = 600
    self.height = 400
    self.initialize_ui()

def initialize_ui(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
    m = InputCanvas(self, width=3, height=3)
    m.move(200, 20)
    self.show()


class InputCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.canvas.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.canvas.setFocus()
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.process_key)
        self.input_plot()

    def input_plot(self):
        volume = io.imread("14.mha", plugin='simpleitk')
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.volume = volume
        ax.index = volume.shape[0] // 2
        ax.set_title('Ground Truth Image')
        plt.set_cmap("gray")
        plt.axis('off')
        ax.imshow(volume[ax.index])
        self.draw()

    def process_key(self, event):
        fig = event.canvas.figure
        ax = fig.axes[0]
        if event.key == 'j':
            self.previous_slice(ax)
        elif event.key == 'k':
            self.ext_slice(ax)
        self.draw()

    def previous_slice(self, ax):
        volume = ax.volume
        ax.index = (ax.index - 1) % volume.shape[0]  # wrap around using %
        ax.images[0].set_array(volume[ax.index])

    def next_slice(self, ax):
        volume = ax.volume
        ax.index = (ax.index + 1) % volume.shape[0]
        ax.images[0].set_array(volume[ax.index])


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = App()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to tell the canvas that it should do something when a key is pressed. You may use matplotlib to do so,

```
self.cid = self.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.process_key)
```

To get rid of the error, consider the error message. *"canvas" has no attribute canvas* is telling you that the canvas does not have itself as attribute. Hence

```
self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
self.setFocus()
```

Comment: i have tried this but still it doesn't work, canvas does not respond.self.FigureCanvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.process_key)
AttributeError: 'InputCanvas' object has no attribute 'FigureCanvas'